# NumPy : normalize column B according to value of column A

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, normalize

Given a NumPy array `[A B]`, were `A` are different indexes and `B` count values.
How can I **normalize** the `B` values according to their `A` value?

I tried:

```
 def normalize(np_array):
    normalized_array = np.empty([1, 2])
    indexes= np.unique(np_array[:, 0]).tolist()

    for index in indexes:
        index_array= np_array[np_array[:, 0] == index]
        mean_id = np.mean(index_array[:, 1])
        std_id = np.std(index_array[:, 1])
        if mean_id * std_id > 0:
            index_array[:, 1] = (index_array[:, 1] - mean_id) / std_id
            normalized_array = np.concatenate([normalized_array, index_array])
    return np.delete(normalized_array, 0, 0) # my apologies
```

which is doing the job, but I'm looking for a more noble way to achieve this.

Any input would be warmly welcome.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `normalized_array` is a function. Certainly it doesn't have an `.append()` method. See in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) how you can initialize an empty array. After that, you should be able to [`.append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can be of help here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
                   'value': [10, 20, 15, 100, 12]})

byid = df.groupby('ID')
mean = byid.mean()
std = byid.std()

df['normalized'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x.value - mean.ix[x.ID]) / std.ix[x.ID], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID  value  normalized
0   1     10   -0.755929
1   1     20    1.133893
2   2     15   -0.707107
3   2    100    0.707107
4   1     12   -0.377964
```

Coming from a NumPy array:

```
>>> a
array([[  1,  10],
       [  1,  20],
       [  2,  15],
       [  2, 100],
       [  1,  12]])
```

You can create your dataframe like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': a[:, 0], 'value': a[:, 1]})
>>> df
   ID  value
0   1     10
1   1     20
2   2     15
3   2    100
4   1     12
```

Comment: It rocks ! Thanks so much.

Comment: `df['normalized'] = df.groupby('ID').transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()) ` 
does also the job.